# Unable to browse localhost due to HSTS common_name_invalid

Tags: asp.net, iis, hsts

Last week I was able to build and run a locally-hosted .NET website without any problems. However, for the past couple of days I haven't been able to get around this error:

> ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

This error message appears in both Chrome and Firefox. Edge and IE will load the page but block all AJAX requests without explanation.

The website is configured as an application in IIS and uses a self-signed certificate (created in IIS).

I encounter the same problem with running a completely separate .NET website so I doubt it has anything to do with each website's individual configurations.

My colleagues are able to browse their locally-hosted versions of the same website using a self-signed certificate in the same browser versions as I have installed.

Please, can someone tell me what might have happened to my setup, why are browsers no longer accepting my certificate, and how to get back to a running localhost website?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a PHP developer and to be able to work on my development environment with a certificate, I was able to do the same by finding the real SSL HTTPS/HTTP Certificate and deleting it.

The steps are :

1. In the address bar, type "chrome://net-internals/#hsts".
2. Type the domain name in the text field below "Delete domain".
3. Click the "Delete" button.
4. Type the domain name in the text field below "Query domain".
5. Click the "Query" button.
6. Your response should be "Not found".

You can find more information at : http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers

Although this solution is not the best, Chrome currently does not have any good solution for the moment. I have escalated this situation with their support team to help improve user/developer experience.

You should redo these steps every time you go on the server that contains the main HTTPS Certificate with HSTS clause.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer, @aneth101. I actually did those steps and wrote it into the draft OP, but the result was that I got a CONNECTION_RESET error every time I tried to load the site thereafter - and across all browsers. I had to use chrome://net-internals/#hsts to _re-add_ the information (using "Add domain") which was the only way to get past the CONNECTION_RESET error. It seemed to me like a side-step so I then removed it from my OP. Very puzzling.

Comment: Yes I've seen this error at some point during my investigation. I've seen people saying to restart the computer and retry. I haven't stumbled upon this problem and the steps worked like a charm for me. I understand why you removed it from your OP.